# loading several resources in partial views using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using ASP.NET MVC5 and angularJS, i have just started learning angular and i'm not so sure on best practice. what i have archived so far is good however not sure if the best approach, all my backend code is finished and i return my results as json in the controller(mvc)

in regards to angularJS i have the following code, is this how it should be done? or there is something better? also the reason why i have ng-click call all methods is that i will have select-ui and passing params to retrieve new data.

note: i have removed a lot of partials the main dashboard has around 20...

main.js

```
var mainModule = angular.module("mainModule", []);

mainModule.factory("appService", ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {

        function getBookingData() {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                httpPromise = $http({ method: "GET", url: "/Main/BookingData" });

            httpPromise.then(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        function getCommissionData() {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                httpPromise = $http({ method: "GET", url: "/Main/CommissionsData" });

            httpPromise.then(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }, function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        return {
            getBookingData: getBookingData,
            getCommissionData: getCommissionData
        };
    }
]);

mainModule.controller("mainController", [
    "$scope", "$q", "appService", function($scope, $q, appService) {
        $scope.getObjects = function() {
            appService.getBookingData()
                .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.bookingArray = response.data;
                    console.log(response);
                }, function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });

            appService.getCommissionData()
                .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.commissionArray = response.data;
                    console.log(response);
                }, function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        };
        $scope.getObjects();
    }
]);
```

index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main";
}

<div class="wrapper wrapper-content" ng-app="mainModule" ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="row">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="getObjects()">Apply</button>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div>@Html.Partial("_Booking")</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div>@Html.Partial("_Commission")</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/main")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your appService code can be much cleaner.  $http already returns promises from its calls, so you don't need any of the explicit $q calls.

```
function getBookingData() {
    return $http({ method: "GET", url: "/Main/BookingData" })
           .catch(function (error) { console.error(error); });
}
```

Is equivalent to your function.  It might be good to review how the promise API works, and experiment with some test projects.

It doesn't look like you do anything with $scope.bookingArray and $scope.commissionArray, but maybe it's in the partials you omitted?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: yes my binding happens in the partial views which works

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Albert Liu's answer regarding promises are correct. I think you can reduce your factory code to this using [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) shortcut methods:

```
mainModule.factory("appService", ["$http", function ($http) { // no need to inject $q

        function getBookingData() {
            return $http.get("/Main/BookingData"); // $http.get shortcut methods returns a promise
        }

        function getCommissionData() {
            return $http.get("/Main/CommissionsData"); // $http.get shortcut methods returns a promise
        }

        return {
            getBookingData: getBookingData,
            getCommissionData: getCommissionData
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.